# Why is my AOP aspect returning null?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

This Before execution code is not working? It is returning `null` because `datap` is not set from `my_int_it_method()` method. `@Before` should have executed `my_int_it_method()` then only `send()` would work.

Aspect AOP code here:

```
package org.main;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class data {
    Connection con = new db_connect().connect();
    String datap;
    String test;

    @Before("execution(public String send())")
    public void my_int_it_method() {

        String query = "Select * from shapes where shape_id=?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt;
        try {
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setInt(1, 2);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()) {
                datap=rs.getString("type");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String send() {
        return datap;
    }   
}
```

XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
    <bean name = "data" class="org.main.data" autowire="byName"/>
</beans>
```

Execution code here:

```
package org.main;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
        data dataa = ctx.getBean("data",data.class);
        dataa.send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining your aspect and target (send method) in the same class.

From the AOP Spring documentation

> In Spring AOP, it is not possible to have aspects themselves be the target of advice from other aspects. The @Aspect annotation on a class marks it as an aspect and hence excludes it from auto-proxying.

In other words, the moment a class is annotated with a `@Aspect` it cannot be proxied, which is needed for AOP to work.

The solution for this is to extract your aspect to a new class. This, however, will cause you some other problems since you will not have access to the `datap` you wanted to set.

I have to be honest I am not sure that your current example is best solved with AOP.

If you wish to read more on AOP have look at the [AOP Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop). It is quite clear with loads of examples.